# EES to Matlab, proces only completes when closing EES manually

Tags: matlab

I'm currently doing some combustion engine analysis which has lead me to try and pass some specific heats from EES to matlab, by using EES-macros (.emf files) to generate the properties. This works great for simple tasks where the properties are just assigned to variables in the macros which is then exported and read by Matlab.

Now, I'm interested in getting the properties of products in chemical equilibrium calculations, so I need to solve coupled equations in EES. This poses a problem since you can't have unassigned stuff on the right hand side in EES-macros.

The above problem was quickly solved simply by solving the equations for the equilibrium composition in a reguler .ees-file and then exporting the results. But this has led to another problem:

Once I call my Matlab-script the procedure starts "hanging" just before the specific heats are returned. I've found that the script completes once you manually close the now-opened EES-window, but this is not viable since i need to make several hundreds of imports.

The problem doesn't occur when using EES-macros instead of files, since in these you can simply use the Quit statement in the end, but as mentioned macros are not an option for this. Does anyone know of an equivalent statement that you can use in an EES-FILE? I've also tried to shut down EES with a system-command in my script: system('taskkill /F /IM EES.EXE');. But this doesn't seem to be able to find the EES-task, although it appears in the task manager and in the taskbar (the statement is tested, it works if you open EES manually).

Any help is very much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Regards

Comment: According to fchart, the equivalent command option is [`/solve`](http://www.fchart.com/ees/eeshelp/hs605.htm).  However, with my current install of EES and Matlab, their system call simply opens an EES instance.  I've submitted the issue through their website. Until there is a fix, the (unsupported) [`dde` method](http://www.fchart.com/ees/eeshelp/lqscv9.htm) works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a macro file to solve the EES file and then quit the program.

`Example.emf` contains:

```
Open C:\Example.ees
Solve
Quit
```

And then the MATLAB system call

```
system('$EESPath\ees.exe C:\Example.emf');
```

will do the job.
You will need to leverage the `$Export` directive to place the results into an external file that MATLAB can then import.

Comment: Hi Troy, 

Your suggestion solved the problem - thanks a bunch! :)